# Как работает оператор new?

Tags: c#, стек, new, куча

```
int[] myarray = new int[10].
```

Я бы хотел узнать у знатоков сам процесс и правильно ли я понял.
Мы объявляем переменную ссылочного типа, она размещается в стеке. Далее оператором `new` мы создаём место в куче (выделяем согласно размеру типа, в данном случае `int`), а далее оператор `new` возвращает адрес, который мы присваиваем переменой ссылочного типа адрес выделенного места в хипе, т.е адрес значения.

`new` возвращает адрес или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы создаёте объект ссылочного типа, например, массив из 10 элементов `int`, как в данном случае, то возвращается `ссылка` на объект. А если создаёте объект типа значение, например, просто целое число, а не массив, то будет возвращён сам объект.

Хотя на низком уровне всё это ещё сложнее выглядит. У обоих этих сущностей и у ссылки и у объекта есть адрес, и его можно при желании [получить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588817/c-sharp-memory-address-and-variable).

В куче или на стеке размещается объект - это ещё один сложный вопрос. Если очень приблизительно, то да - ссылка или, например, структура будет на стеке, а объект будет в куче. Или даже в куче больших объектов `LOH`, если он достаточно большой. Но всё это не гарантировано на 100%. Есть ещё регистры процессора и другие тонкости.